# Basis of sum and intersection of two subspaces.

Tags: linear-algebra

I have two vector subspaces:

$U=span ((1,1,0,-1), (1,2,3,0), (-1,-2,-3,0)) \\ V=span ((1,2,2,-2), (2,3,2,-3), (1,3,4,-3))$

Now i have to find $B_{U+V}$ and $B_{U\cap V}$

For $B_{U+V}$ u have to fin$B_U$ and $B_V$ first, which are relatively easy to find:

$B_U=((1,1,0,-1), (1,2,3,0)) \\ B_V = ((1,2,2,-2), (2,3,2,-3))$

Now i have to take these four vectors and four arbitrary real numbers and solve corresponding system of equations in order to see what happens:

$ \alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta \in \mathbb{R} \\ \alpha(1,1,0,-1) + \beta(1,2,3,0) + \gamma(1,2,2,-2) + \delta(2,3,2,-3) = (0,0,0,0)$

$\alpha + \beta + \gamma + 2\delta=0 \\ \alpha + 2\beta + 2\gamma + 3\delta = 0 \\ 0\alpha+2\beta + 2\gamma + 2\delta = 0 \\ -\alpha+0\beta-2\gamma-3\delta=0$

From the fourth equation we have $\alpha=-2\gamma-3\delta$ which means that alpha is dependent variable

$\beta -\gamma -\delta = 0 \\ \beta=0 \\ 3\beta+2\gamma+2\delta = 0$

Since $\beta=0$ it means that we have only two equations left, but they are equivalent which means that we have only one left $\gamma + \delta = 0 \Rightarrow \gamma=-\delta$ which means that gamma is dependent variable too.

Now, if variable is dependent, it's corresponding vector (vector that's multiplied by that variable is independent) which means that first and third vectors are linearly independent, and since $\delta$ is independent, it's vector is dependent, so it is not the element of the basis of the subspace.

Since $\beta=0$ does that means that second vector is dependent or independent (i'd like explanation here along with the answer)?

How can i find $B_{U\cap V}$?

Comment: Your third equation $2\beta+2\gamma+2\delta=0$ is wrong. Solving the correct equations you get $\beta=0,\alpha=\gamma=-\delta$. In other words, $(1,1,0,-1)=(2,3,2,-3)-(1,2,2,-2)$. So you can conclude that $\beta,\gamma,\delta$ are a basis for $U+V$ and that $\alpha$ is a basis for $U\cap V$.

Comment: @almagest I see, i wrote 2 instead of 3 but, in general, when i have two dependent values, one independent and one being constant as a solutions to the system of equations how can i know is the vector multiplied by constant value scalar (in this case it was zero) dependent or independet, is it always like in this example ans why?  How can i know that $\alpha$ is the basis of intersection of subspaces?

Comment: Your solution shows you: (A) that $(1,1,0,-1)$ is a linear combination of $(2,3,2,-3)$ and $(1,2,2,-2)$ so it belongs to $V$; (B) that there is no solution with $\beta\ne0$, so $(1,2,3,0)\notin V$; (C) that there is no solution with $\gamma=\delta=0$, so $(1,1,0,-1)$ and $(1,2,3,0)$ are linearly independent; and (D) that there is no solution with $\alpha=0$, so  $(1,2,3,0)$,$(1,2,2,-2)$ and $(2,3,2,-3)$ are linearly independent.

Comment: @almagest Ok, thank you, i understand (A) and (B) now, and (A) implies that $(1,1,0,-1)$ is in intersection of these two subspaces, but how can i know that there is no more vectors in the intersection and what about (C) and (D)? How can i know that there is no solution with $\gamma = \delta= 0$ or with $\alpha=0$? I mean, $\alpha$ and $\gamma$ depend on $\delta$ so in this case if $\delta$ is not zero, they are not either, but why $\delta$ can't be zero? There are no restrictions for it as far as i can see, it should be arbitrary real number.

Comment: $\delta$ can be 0. But then $\alpha=\gamma=0$ too.

Comment: @almagest And why that isn't possible?